# Detecting current device in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying out released VS 2013 Update 2 and building a sample Universal Application.

I have created a user control and on both MainPages added GridViews (on Windows Phone and Windows 8).

I want to change some things via code when app is running on Windows Phone.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
if(<deviceType> == "WindowsPhone")
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally when building your app, you can use preprocessor directives. When building app for windows phone, VS as default defines `WINDOWS_PHONE_APP` (take a look at Project Properties -> Build -> Conditional compilation symbols). Therefore anywhere in your code you can put such a statement:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    // do when this is compiled as Windows Phone App
#else
    // not for windows phoen
#endif
```

More information you can get [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx).

I would advise to use this approach, hence in most cases you know exactly when you will use specific code for Phone (ARM) or other platform. Of course if you need you can define more symbols for specific build configurations/platforms.

Remarks: Since W10, where you need to check the platform in *Run-Time*, then you can use [ApiInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation) and check if specific type exists in the api. For example like this:

```cs
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Phone.PhoneContract", 1))
   // do code for mobile
else 
   // do code for other
```

Comment: DO you have any example of using this ApiInformation class? Couldnt find any so far...

Comment: @SpartacusRocha Take [a look at other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32350032/2681948), though personally I use the checkup for a different contract. Nevertheless as packages are being build for specific platform - I use conditional symbols where I can, then there is no need to detect platform at runtime.

Comment: Note that the presence of the `PhoneContract` doesn't prove it's a phone - it just proves that *the APIs from that contract are available*. Luckily, nobody has shipped a non-phone device with the Phone contract, but in general this is a poor way to test things out.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT You are right. I still would just make other package for specific device, api contract is mostly used in some rare cases and just in places where I need the API rather than the device type. Do you know easier/better way to get device type?

Comment: The problem is really "what do you mean by device type?" A "phone" can have a Desktop-like experience (Continuum). A "desktop" can have a tablet-like experience or a HoloLens-like experience (Mixed reality). Unfortunately we don't have great tools for handling all these cases right now :/. `AnalyticsInfo` is the best approximation we have today for "Mobile" vs "PC", but typically you want to look at other things like "how big is the screen", "is there a keyboard attached" and so on.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yeah, right, the device type seems to lose meaning these days.

Answer (score 7):

That's what worked for me in Universal Windows (Windows 10) project

```
public static Platform DetectPlatform()
{
    bool isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent =
        ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons");

    if (isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent)
    {
        return Platform.WindowsPhone;
    }
    else
    {
        return Platform.Windows;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect solution for UWP

Comment: Note that the presence of the `HardwareButtons` type doesn't prove it's a phone - it just proves that *the `HardwareButtons` type exists*. So far nobody has shipped a non-phone device with that API, but in general this is a poor way to test things out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an in-code method of determining the current device, you could try this:

```
public Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Platform DetectPlatform()
{
    try
    {
        //Calls an unsupported API.
        Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader.RequestUncontrainedDownloadsAsync(null);
    }
    catch (NotImplementedException)
    {
        //The API isn't supported on Windows Phone. Thus, the current platform is Windows Phone.
        return Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Platform.WindowsPhone;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
       //Otherwise, this is Windows (desktop/RT).
       return Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Platform.Windows;
    }
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/Amrykid/2fd65ae1815a928fe753

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is a bad idea; there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

OR you can do this

Add this to

> App.Xaml.Cs

```
public static bool IsMobile
{
    get
    {
        var qualifiers = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues;
        return (qualifiers.ContainsKey("DeviceFamily") && qualifiers["DeviceFamily"] == "Mobile");
    }
}
```

Comment: Device Family is a good approximation (not perfect, but typically the best you can do if you really want to detect Mobile). It is easier to get the value from `AnalyticsInfo` though.

Answer (score 1):

From GitHub

```
public static class DeviceTypeHelper
{
    public static DeviceFormFactorType GetDeviceFormFactorType()
    {
        switch (AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily)
        {
            case "Windows.Mobile":
                return DeviceFormFactorType.Phone;
            case "Windows.Desktop":
                return UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode == UserInteractionMode.Mouse
                    ? DeviceFormFactorType.Desktop
                    : DeviceFormFactorType.Tablet;
            case "Windows.Universal":
                return DeviceFormFactorType.IoT;
            case "Windows.Team":
                return DeviceFormFactorType.SurfaceHub;
            default:
                return DeviceFormFactorType.Other;
        }
    }
}

public enum DeviceFormFactorType
{
    Phone,
    Desktop,
    Tablet,
    IoT,
    SurfaceHub,
    Other
}
```

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wagonli/40d8a31bd0d6f0dd7a5d/raw/f6175de5fcad40cc257edc3748c0e349495d17f6/DeviceTypeHelper.cs

Answer (score -1):

It's a workaround

```
       //PC customization
                if(ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView"))
                {
                }

                //Mobile customization
                if(ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
                {
                }
```

Comment: That's a very bad way to check, and is buggy -- starting with Windows 10, [The `ApplicationView` class is available on all platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView). Given that it's the same OS release that `ApiInformation` was introduced, this code should never have worked.