# MIME type to extension Windows Universal app

Tags: c#, windows, mime-types, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a Windows Universal App in c#. I get a MIME type from my server and I have to save a file with the extension that that MIME type represents. How can I convert this MIME type to a file extension in a way that works with Windows Universal Apps, so with both Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1?

I don't mind a:

```
#if Windows_Phone
{code}
#elif
{code}
#endif
```

Construction.

Comment: If you don't mind such a construction then [maybe this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23268242/2681948).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However that doesn't explain anything about converting MIME type into file extensions.

Comment: Yes, I know, I've just added how the #if construction may look like. For now I won't be alble to help you with MIME type conversion, maybe somebody else will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to the Registry or any similar Windows magic, neither in W8 nor in WP8. There's only one exception I know of: `Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.GetDecoderInformationEnumerator()` tells you both about mimetypes and extensions, but only of image formats installed on the local machine.

You'll probably need to manually create a dictionary which maps from mimetype to extension. 
Be warned: this is a neverending task. E.g. the mimetype "audio/x-mpegurl" has two extensions: .m3u and .m3u8. At the same time many servers claim that .m3u files have the mimetype "audio/m3u". So you'll end up tweaking and updating this dictionary over and over ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no platform API available for this. You will need to create your own mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have a suggestion on how to do this? I was googling a bit and found options that used registry keys, but this is not available on windows phone and windows store apps (as far as I know).