# C# Identify if code is running in Windows Phone or Tablet/Computer

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I need to identify if my code is running on Windows Phone 10 or Windows 10. Have tried with this code, without success:

```
       public static Platform DetectaPlataforma()
    {
        bool APIBotoesPresent = ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons");
        if (APIBotoesPresent)
        {
            (App.Current as App).Telefone = true;
            return Platform.WindowsPhone;
        }
        else
        {
            (App.Current as App).Telefone = false;
            return Platform.Windows;
        }
    }
```

It Always detects Windows, even when being run at Phone. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this post it might be solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267992/detecting-current-device-in-windows-universal-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know exactly why, but it Works like a charm if I dont use App variable, but instead, check on each code, like this:

```
        private async void btnFinanceiro_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
        {
            MessageDialog dialogo = new MessageDialog("My message!");
            await dialogo.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            frmPrincipal.Navigate(typeof(Financeiro));
        }
    }
```

On the other hand, when I try this way, it dont work:

```
        private async void btnProntuario_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((App.Current as App).Telefone)
        {
            MessageDialog dialogo = new MessageDialog("My message!");
            await dialogo.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            frmPrincipal.Navigate(typeof(Prontuario));
        }
    }
```

On the App.xaml.cs I use this:

```
        public static Platform DetectaPlataforma()
    {
        if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
        {
            (App.Current as App).Telefone = true;
            return Platform.WindowsPhone;
        }
        else
        {
            (App.Current as App).Telefone = false;
            return Platform.Windows;
        }
    }
```

Seems odd for me, but at least its working now.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to

> App.XAML.CS

```
public static bool IsMobile
{
    get
    {
        var qualifiers = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues;
        return (qualifiers.ContainsKey("DeviceFamily") && qualifiers["DeviceFamily"] == "Mobile");
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer , please mark it as an answer

Comment: Didnt work, still recognizing as Windows even when its Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Phone.PhoneContract", 1))
   // do code for mobile
else 
   // do code for other
```

Comment: aah ! Finally it helped you :) Great !